# Need to write Query with condition

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

I need to write a single query

If a record id already exists in table, and the same record id with some different values is 
then I have to update its expiry date in the table and also insert the record id with new values to the table.
If not record id not present then make a new entry to the table .

Eg: In a table tmp record_id =101 exists then update main_table expiry_date of all the rows with record id='101' and also insert a new row from tmp to main_table else insert into main_table.

Comment: Have you tried anything? At least show us the table schema please :)

Comment: I tried to use Merge but it wont work update/insert simulataneously right.. bcos im ny case I need to update the expiry date of all the rows with the record id and insert a new row.else insert new row

Answer (score 3):

You need a [Merge statement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm) and an insert:

```
merge into your_table t
using(select 5 as id, sysdate as expiry_date from source where coditions) S
on(s.id = t.id)
when matched then update t.expiry_date = s.expiry_date;

insert into your_table t   
values (5 , sysdate);
```

Comment: When matched I need to insert the new row also despite being update.Ur mising tat

Comment: :can we write under matched two dml stmts?

Comment: @Satheesh as I said to bonCodigo, no. On `Matched` you can `update where ` and `when not matched` you can insert with `where`.

Comment: @ FLORIN So is there an other option to do this?? if not merge some with clause or other options

Comment: see my answer. Merge those ids and then insert them. If the row does not exist it will not be merged. However, it will be inserted on second statement.

Comment: If you have other conditions that could be compared, then there could be a slim chance add `a case when within the when matched`, otherwise Florin's answer seems the most suitable.

Comment: Ouch. The question states "a single Query". @Satheesh , pls explain in the question why do you need a single query. Maybe we can offer a better solution.

Comment: Its fine :) If v cant do that.. The requirements stated me to a write single query. i will suggest not to do.

Answer (score 1):

Check this one please:

```
MERGE INTO mytable b
USING (SELECT * from mytable where id = 10) a
ON b.id = a.id
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET b.expirydate = a.expirydate
;
INSERT (id, col1, col2...) VALUES (a.id, col1, col2...)
```

In the event of matched you will update. At all times you will insert.

Comment: you don't have that option on [merge statement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm) (I refer to `and insert`)

Comment: @FlorinGhita I had a typo, I meant to say we use `when matched` twice :) for the `upsert`

Comment: @Satheesh, how about this, logically it makese very less sense to me.. ;) you may give this a try, when matched you will do the `upsert` (don't have a oracle matchine to try this) let me give this a try on fiddle.

Comment: @FlorinGhita I think your answer makes more sense, coz OP wants to insert anyway. So `when matched` just update only. Then insert separately.